# How can a scrollviewer be used against a complex XAML page that includes Grids, StackPanels and a ListView?

Tags: listview, uwp-xaml

I have a long UWP XAML page including a great number of controls including Grids, StackPanels and a ListView at the end.   I tried wrapping the entire stack in a ScrollViewer but nothing on the page scrolls vertically.  The page is quite long so its not practical to paste in here as an example but essentially I'd like to render the fixed content controls along with the ListView and be able to scroll the entire view vertically.   I know the ListView includes a scrollviewer in its style template but I haven't found an override that works.

I think what I am looking for is rather than enabling scrolling within the ListView I'd like all of its items to contribute to its overall height and then be able to render all of its items at once and include them in the combo view as I scroll through the entire page.

And later once I have that working, I'd want to look into an action that fetches additional items from the ListView datasource so that if I initially render say 50 items, after scrolling down to the end, I can swipe up and the fetch more items to add to the ListView.

Anyone know how to create this unified scroll behavior to control all controls on a XAML page?

Comment: If you could not provide your XAML layout, it's hard to help you diagnose why the ScrollViewer cannot scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a long UWP XAML page including a great number of controls including Grids, StackPanels and a ListView at the end. I tried wrapping the entire stack in a ScrollViewer but nothing on the page scrolls vertically.

- Ensure the `ScrollViewer` isn't a Child of a `StackPanel`, as the `ScrollViewer` (if you didn't give it a `height` or `max-height`) will expand to its full height in a `StackPanel`

> I'd like to render the fixed content controls along with the ListView and be able to scroll the entire view vertically.

I assume you mean you want the 'content controls' to move along with the `ScrollViewer`. I would recommend a structure similar to this:

```
Grid > ScrollViewer > StackPanel > Grid > Controls & a StackPanel wrapping your ListView
```

Here is a Sample (Very Messy - Use Proper Layout in Grid (Not Margins))
Remember to put your controls after the ListView in the XAML, the elements later in the document are rendered at the top.

```
<Grid>
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <ListView>
                <ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem><ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="140,40,0,0" Text="Other Controls"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

> I'd want to look into an action that fetches additional items from the ListView datasource so that if I initially render say 50 items, after scrolling down to the end, I can swipe up and the fetch more items to add to the ListView.

- Use the `IncrementalLoadingCollection` from the **Microsoft UWP Community Toolkit**

After installing the Package from Nuget, Create a Helper Class with a Method Similar to below (Taken from the Community Toolkit Sample)
Here `People` is the Class Type being shown in the ListView. All you have to do is return a list for the given parameters.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
// Gets items from the collection according to pageIndex and pageSize parameters.
    var result = (from p in people
                    select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    // Simulates a longer request...
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    return result;
 }
```

Create a `IncrementalLoadingCollection` and Bind it to your ListView.
Below `HelperClass` represents the Helper Class that includes the method from the previous step. I haven't included the binding step, but it works just like any other list. You can do it either in XAML or in code behind with something like `MyListView.ItemSource = collection;`

```
IncrementalLoadingCollection collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<HelperClass, Person>();
```

**For a more extensive sample (with included xaml playground) take a look at the http://aka.ms/uwptoolkitapp sample app for the toolkit.** You can find the `IncrementalLoadingCollection` under the `Helpers` tab.